Why does wait return 127 only if lastpipe is enabled?
I don't understand why wait returns 127 in this case. According to man bash, this happens if the subprocess does not exist anymore. This seems to not be the case.
This is the minimal example:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s lastpipe                                                                           

echo text | {                                                                               
    tr a-z A-Z <&0 &
    wait -n -f 
}
echo Exit code: $?

It works as expected if lastpipe is not enabled. In need to use option -n since the original scripts runs two processes and I need to continue before all background tasks have been finished.
Why is that? It's really getting me down.
Below is a more sophisticated example showing the same issue for try1(), but it works for try2():
#!/usr/bin/env bash

execute() (                                                                                 
    if $BACKGROUND; then                                                                    
        "$@" <&0 &                                                                          
        wait -n -f
    else
        "$@"                                                                                
    fi  
)

try1() {
    echo try1 |                                                                             
    execute tr a-z A-Z                                                                      
}

try2() {
    execute tr a-z A-Z < <(echo try2)                                                       
}

testIt() {
    echo                                                                                    
    echo "BACKGROUND=$BACKGROUND"                                                           
    for TRY in try1 try2; do
        $TRY
        echo $?
    done
}

shopt -s lastpipe

BACKGROUND=true  testIt
BACKGROUND=false testIt


What's the purpose of putting the command in the background to just wait for it  right after?

@ilkkachu presumably to be able to give us a simple, concise example that reproduces the issue.

What man page are you looking at? If you are looking at man wait, that isn't relevant here as you are using the shell builtin wait and not ``/usr/bin/wait. See help wait` from a bash shell instead.

@terdon, well, I suppose I'm wondering what the underlying use case is (i.e. which parts are simplified for the sake if an example and which parts are part if the purpose). Given the mention of lastpipe, I expect the pipes might be key here, but then again backgrounding one part if a pipeline also seems a bit odd. (Wouldn't the shell wait for the other parts anyway? So what's the gain compared to a regular foreground pipeline?)

So, this is caused by the -n option (which is only available to the shell builtin). Removing the -n makes it work as expected. Not posting an answer since I don't understand the details here, but -n means "wait for the next job to complete" so here there are no next jobs (possibly because the tr has already finished?) so there's nothing to wait for. I hope someone who knows the internals of the shell better can post an answer.

@ilkkachu dunno, but this is an interesting question regardless. No matter what the OP might really be trying to do, the question of why wait behaves as it does is useful so we might as well focus on that.

That looks like a bug. I hits this, upon wait -n, where jobs_list_frozen has been set there earlier. You can always move the wait -n out of the command group and pipeline.

Yes, it's a as much as possible simplified version of a quite complex script which still shows the issue.
The original script runs two processes in the background (one is some kind of watchdog for a timeout).

I've consulted man bash itself and help wait as well, but I've focused on the manpage.

Afaik I need to use -n since I want handle the watchdog, hence I need to continue before all jobs are done.

@StéphaneChazelas, if would be a great finding imho of it materialise as a bug. ;)

I need to check if it is possible to pull the wait out of the pipe. It might, but needs a huge refactoring for sure.
